# Bundle install a local pg gem without internet access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, pg

I'm on a remote server with **no internet access**.
Have a Rails app.
Trying to `bundle install` (All gems were cached using [bundle package --all](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-package.1.html) to `app/vendor/cached`)

Since no internet connection I'm using the `--local` flag (Tells `bundle` to use cached values- [link](https://bundler.io/v1.17/man/bundle-install.1.html)): Running `bundle install --local` fails saying:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that "gem install pg -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org'" succeeds before bundling.
```

Now the cached gem is at app folder at `app/vendor/cached/pg.1.1.4.gem`
It only happen with the `pg` gem.

Usually I solve this problem using: `bundle config build.pg --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10` (Which basically tells bundle to use those arguments when installing `pg`). But that's when I have internet connection.

Now I can install pg manually using this command:
`gem install --local app/vendor/cached/pg.1.1.4.gem  -- --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10`
Notice there are two parts for the arguments, separated by `--`:

1. `--local app/vendor/cached/pg.1.1.4.gem`
2. `--with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10`

So the first part of the arguments: `--local app/vendor/cached/pg.1.1.4.gem`

How do I get bundle to do it?
At my workstation where I have internet connection I still got that error but use this to fix it:
`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10` Which basically tells bundle to use those arguments when installing `pg`

But now additionally bundle need also to use a **local path**? I guess? (like the gem install command uses?
It tries to connect to `rubygems.org`

**To summarize: how to make `bundle install` install a local `pg gem`? or convert the previously shown working gem install command to bundle install command?**

`ruby 2.5.3`, `rails 5.2.1`, `bundler 1.17.3`

output for `bundle config`:

`build.pg (/home/myuser/.bundle/config): "--with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10"`

I tried several combinations using the `bundle config build.pg` command but no success:

- bundle config build.pg --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10
- bundle config build.pg --local app/vendor/cached/pg.1.1.4.gem -- --with-pg-include=/usr/pgsql-10/include --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by running
`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-10/bin/pg_config`.